# Data Loader (or any API data import) logging / history

Tags: data-loader, data, import, logging, dataloader.io

Where do I find a log and/or history of **data import/export calls via the API in Salesforce?**  I know where to find Bulk call logs, but we don't typically call upon the Bulk option so nothing is listed there.

I can't fathom why I do not recall this, and cannot find any help no matter how I Google it.  My role in the past 15 months has shifted twice, and I have not looked at this in at least that long.  Thanks.   #duh  #lostknowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**API Calls**

[Documentation Link](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003706)

> Go to Monitor | System Overview and there you will find the API REQUESTS, LAST 24 HOURS. This shows you how many API calls you've made in the last 24 hours including today. For example, if you are viewing this on Monday at 2:30 PM, it'll show you the calls made since Sunday at 2:30 PM

Reports>Adminstrative Reports>API Usage Last 7 Days gives the SOAP API useage but not the REST API useage.

As per documentation

> The "API Usage last 7 days" report shows you the calls made by user and date for the last 7 days including today. Take into account that the counters for this report reset at 12am Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) or UTC.
>
> NOTE: This report displays SOAP API usage, but REST API (including
>   Bulk API) calls are not included in the report, which might explain
>   why the data displayed in the report does not match the figure
>   returned by the System Overview page.

And the last option using the [EventLogFile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm) using SOQL.

**Bulk Load**

Go to Setup>Monitor>Jobs>Bulk Data Load jobs

[Salesforce help](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=monitoring_async_api_jobs.htm&language=en_US)

Important fact the information is not retained for any length of time

> Completed jobs are removed from the list seven days after completion.

---

**Note by AMM:**  Accepting this answer, as I plan to just use Bulk calls as the default from now on for tracking purposes.  Caveat is that you cannot do "null inserts" using Bulk API.

[enter link description here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=loader_using_bulk_api.htm%20Article%20About%20Bulk%20API%20and%20DataLoader)

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear about the Bulk Data Load jobs - fixing the verbiage on my post.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I'll update for the other types but leave bulk data in

Comment: Just can't crack this.  I can of course report on Logins, but that has no detail (number of records, etc).  It MAY be as simple as... clicking Bulk API in DataLoader, so that it's used and I can see them in the Bulk Logs in the GUI.  May not always be viable when I have to disable it though.   Ugh.

Comment: I'm just going to accept this answer, but note the link to the article that let's people know the IMPACT of using the Bulk methodology (main thing for me is when I want to do null inserts).   https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=loader_using_bulk_api.htm